# Access a value with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access a value with `ng-repeat`. I need to access the value of `QuestionID`. I tried `value.QuestionID` but it didn't work.

### JSON

```json
[
  {
    "QuestionID": 101,
    "Question": "q1",
    "Response": "a1.1",
    "CorrectResponse": false
  },
  {
    "QuestionID": 101,
    "Question": "q1",
    "Response": "a1.2",
    "CorrectResponse": true
  }
]
```

### HTML

```html
<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
   <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'Question'">
      Question name: {{ key }}
      <li ng-repeat="answer in value">
         {{ answer.Response }}
      </li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you grouped by 'Question', your 'QuestionID' will be inside "`answer`"

```
<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
   <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'Question'">
      Question name: {{ key }}

      <span>{{ value[0].QuestionID }}</span>

      <li ng-repeat="answer in value">
         {{ answer.Response }}
         <!-- {{ answer.QuestionID }} -->
      </li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is working. How can I pass this value to a function.I tired that: <md-button  ng-click="openQuestionToEdit({{value[0].QuestionID}})">Edit</md-button>

Comment: @user6934713 Just remove the double curly braces and confirm it's inside the `ng-repeat` scope